# User birth date params not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a small rails app, but i'm having trouble getting some information that i'm trying to implement into the user to save. My app as of right now asks for a username and password for signing up. I did this by using the devise gem. However I want to also add an age check to the app, and this is where i've been running into problems.

My DB column is set at (in my schema)

```
t.date "birth_date"
```

My view is at

```
<%= f.input :birth_date, required: true, start_year:1900 %>
```

My controller has two parts to it:

```
def create
  @user = current_user.build(user_params)
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:birth_date)
end
```

Whenever i try to log in and create a birth_date for my new user, in the console when I check, the birth_date is still set at nil.  Would anyone know what i am missing with this? (I think i'm getting tripped up with Devise handling some things already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do input `birth_date` of the user as a part of sign_up process and using devise for this purpose you need to whitelist `birth_date` params explicitly.

Best way of doing that is using your own `registerations_controller` and inheriting it from devise

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: :create
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: :update

  protected
    # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_sign_up_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:birth_date])
    end

    # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_account_update_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:bith_date])
    end

end


#in routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations"}
```

Comment: Hey bud, thanks so much! (had the controller in the wrong spot for a while, but figured it out!!)

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this your UsersController, separate from Devise controllers, you just need to save it to db:

```
def create
  @user = current_user.update(user_params)
end
```

But you might need to change the birthday in params (which is a string) to a date object first, depending on your column type.

Also you might consider moving this to #update as this is really more an `#update` action than `#create`.

Answer (score 0):

since you using devise, and additional field while register, I think you should overwrite devise, [here is link for reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb), create registration controller as follow

**app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do
        resource.birth_date = params[:birth_date]
        resource.save
    end
  end
end
```

make sure you also have devise routes

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```